# How to paginate and orderBy when getting data from relation model in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I want to order by `created_at` posts in **descending** order

I also would like to paginate posts.

My issue is, I am not getting data directly through `Post` Model, I don't know how to do this.

I am using Laravel 5.7. This is what I have written inside a function in HomeController.

```
$id = auth()->user()->id;
$user = User::find($id);
return view('home')->with('posts',$user->posts);
```

Thank You.

Comment: Aren't [Laravel doc(pagination)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination#paginating-eloquent-results)  & [Laravel doc(latest)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) straightforward enough?

Comment: Yeah, they are straight as a circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$posts = auth()->user()->posts()->latest()->paginate();
return view('home', compact('posts'));
```